# Python regexp problem in Ansible playbook

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I have a string in Zabbix agent configuration like

```
HostMetadata=Linux
```

I want change it with variable "nginx" to:

```
HostMetadata=Linux nginx
```

This changes must be idempotent. But when I am using code twice, line changed to

```
HostMetadata=Linux nginx nginx
```

My code:

```yaml
      - name: regexp
        lineinfile:
          path: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
          regexp: '^(HostMetadata=Linux.*)$'
          line:  '\1 nginx'
          backrefs: yes
        tags: regexp
```

I tried "^HostMetadata=((?!nginx).)*$", but it breaks next step, and result will be "x nginx"

I want create reusable code and add new parameters. For example:

```
VAR=nginx
"HostMetadata=Linux" -> "HostMetadata=Linux nginx"

VAR=apache
"HostMetadata=Linux nginx" ->  "HostMetadata=Linux nginx apache"

VAR=nginx
"HostMetadata=Linux nginx apache" -> "HostMetadata=Linux nginx apache" (nothing changed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only capture the part you need to keep, the rest should be just matched.

You may use

```
regexp: '^(HostMetadata=Linux).*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aaO8NX/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(HostMetadata=Linux)` - capturing group #1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement string): the literal string
- `.*` - the rest of the string to the end, any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry, this is my first quiestion =) I added more description to question.

Comment: @AlxiRus So, try `^(HostMetadata=Linux(?!.*nginx).*)`

Comment: @AlxiRus Is that better?

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I want!